# jQuery calling method from clicking button with enter key

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jQuery script is an AJAX that loads data retrieved from servlet when the search button is clicked. I tried to link the enter key so that it would also search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search_button').click(function loadDoc(){
                var search_value = $('#terms').val().trim();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "SearchTermsServlet",
                    data: {
                        terms: search_value
                    },
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data){
                        $('#outershell').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).keypress(function(event){
                if(event.which==13){
                    $('#search_button').click();
                }
            });
        });
```

The function for retrieving data thru enter key works, however it does not reload the page, meaning the "success: function(data){...}" part is not called. How do I fix this?

```
(search_button = id of input of type button)
(SearchTermsServlet = Name of servlet)
(terms = Name of input of type text)
(outershell = div where new information is loaded)
```

HTML code for terms.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Terms: Chemistry Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="termsformat.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search_button').click(function loadDoc(){
                var search_value = $('#terms').val().trim();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "SearchTermsServlet",
                    data: {
                        terms: search_value
                    },
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data){
                        $('#outershell').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).keypress(function(event){
                if(event.which==13){
                    $('#search_button').click();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2> Chemistry Database: Terms Edition</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form name="termform">
            <a class="active" href="chem.html">Home</a>
            <input type="text" id="terms" name = "terms" placeholder="&nbsp;Term..."/>
            <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="outershell">
    </div>   
    <div style="position: relative; background-color: #0f0f0f; height: 500px;width:100%">    
        <div id="footer">
             Creator: Ethan Y.[Ie Yusen] &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact: ethan202y@gmail.com
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know "function for retrieving data thru enter key works" if `success: function(data){...}` is not called?

Comment: In the servlet, I added a println statement such that it would be called every time data was passed thru and also print out the same search result that the user typed. If you really want, I can show you my entire code.

Comment: I dont think servlet coding has got to do anything with this..... so you are saying both click of `$('#search_button')` and pressing `'Enter'` key successfully call `/SearchTermsServlet`, but only click of `$('#search_button')` gets the `data` back?. Is `$('#terms')` a part of the form inside html? In that case may be pressing `Enter` key is submitting the form. Please share the html code

Comment: I've added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your event listener to tell the `<form>` tag to listen for the `submit` event, and fetch the data then. That would cover both clicking the search button as well as hitting the enter key. You'll also want to [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in your event listener.

So your code would become:

```js
$('form[name="termform"]').submit(function loadDoc(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // So the form won't submit
  // The rest of your existing code goes here
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the help.